# node.js vm and external methods

Tags: javascript, node.js, virtual-machine

I have a few problems working on an app that uses `vm`:

External methods calls inside an infinite `while (true) {}` loop are not timed out:

```
var context = {
    externalMethod: function(str) {console.log(str)}
};
vm.runInNewContext("while (true) {externalMethod('test')}", context, {}, 100);
```

Code above runs infinitely, even after 100ms timeout is finished;

```
vm.runInNewContext("for (;;) {}", {}, {}, 100)
```

Also this.. Even without running external methods, it isn't timed out.

And one last question: how safe is it to have external method calls inside `vm2` that will run untrusted code:

```
var context = {
    method: (str) => {
        createMessage("id", str) // some external (non-sandbox) method that sends an authenticated POST request to a chat app...
    }
}
```

So, is it possible to retrieve external `global` or `this`, using that method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Code above runs infinitely, even after 100ms timeout is finished

`timeout` should be a property of the `options` object, not a separate argument:

```
vm.runInNewContext("while (true) {externalMethod('test')}", context, { timeout : 100 })
```

> And one last question: how safe is it to have external method calls inside `vm2` that will run untrusted code.

I assume you mean `vm` (the built-in Node module) and not [`vm2`](https://github.com/patriksimek/vm2) here. In that case, when you call code outside of the VM, it can potentially access the globals, locals and `this` of the "outside" code:

```
const vm    = require('vm');
let SECRET  = 'this is a secret';
let context = {
  console, // to allow `console.log()` calls inside the sandboxed code
  externalMethod() {
    console.log('Secret outside:', SECRET)
  }
};
vm.runInNewContext(`
console.log('Secret inside: ', typeof SECRET);
externalMethod();
`, context);
```

You can't access `SECRET` directly from the 'inside' code, but the external method can access it. So if `externalMethod` has the potential of running untrusted code, it'll be unsafe.

Comment: Awesome answer, and another quick question: `vm2` (the modified vm module) prevents external methods non-sandboxed from getting locals, globals or this inside of the sandbox, by decontextifying?

Comment: @Aurieh you'd have to try yourself, I don't actually have any experience with `vm2` myself :)